# BOOTSTRAP 4 and @include media-breakpoint-up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding the best practices for making several elements of the website responsive.

What do you think about using the following example:

```
#site-header-logo img { 

// Padding top right bottom left //
padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
width: 260px;
height: 40px;


}

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    #site-header-logo img  {
        width: 260px;
        height: 40px;
    }
}
```

Or for example something like this:

```
#site-header-logo-home { 

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    @include make-col(4); 

}
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    @include make-col(12);
}
}
```

Do you have any opinion about it? I found this to work with exception of Safari. Is this good or are there any other option on how to work do similar things?

thank you in advance, 
Best regards, 
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Your question isn't well thought out... it doesn't really make sense to use what you've put. I would *highly* recommend you view some guides on YouTube regarding Bootstrap.

To make something 'responsive', *generally*, you need to use percentage based values.

e.g.

```
#site-header-logo img { 
 // Padding top right bottom left
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

This will make the image grow to its parent's width. It will also shrink down when you resize since you haven't statically set a fixed width.

Comment: thank you for answering. perhaps the question wasn't formulated in the right way but still, in my point of view valid. We can change size with percentage. but imagine I want to add a different colour on the background in another break point? best regards, Luis